# Neo4j/cypher query optiminzation

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The query below is attempting to find all subtypes of a concept within an ontology.  Once all concepts are identified, the query attempts to identify all concepts within the hierarchy that are defined as "primitive" (a property definitionStatusId) and which have supertype and subtype concepts that are defined as "fully defined" (using the same property definitionStatusId).

The number of concepts in the hierarchy is 101,000 (several million paths), the total number of "primitive" concepts = 56,000, and the total number of non-leaf node primitives = 13,000.

The webadmin hangs when executing the query.  So, it is obviously not written well.  I am trying to reduce the scope of the query at each step, but certainly I am not doing it correctly!

Suggestions?

```
//Find all clinical finding subtypes
MATCH (a:ObjectConcept{sctid:404684003})<-[:ISA*]-(b:ObjectConcept)
with collect (DISTINCT b) as set1
//Find all primitive subtypes of clinical findings
UNWIND set1 as x1
MATCH x1
WHERE x1.definitionStatusId = 900000000000074008
with collect (DISTINCT x1) as prim,set1
//Find all fully-defined subtypes of clinical findings
UNWIND set1 as x2
MATCH x2
WHERE x2.definitionStatusId = 900000000000073002
with collect (DISTINCT x2) as full, prim
//Find all primitives with a fully-defined subtype
UNWIND prim as prim1
UNWIND full as full1
MATCH prim1,full1
WHERE EXISTS((prim1)<-[:ISA*]-(full1)) as prim11
with collect (DISTINCT prim11) as intprim, full1
//Find all high level primitives with a fully-defined supertype
UNWIND intprim as intprim1
MATCH intprim1,full1
WHERE EXISTS((full1)<-[:ISA*]-(intprim1)) as intprim11
with collect (DISTINCT intprim11) as intprim2
//Find all high level primitives with fully defined supertypes
//that also have fully defined subtypes
UNWIND intprim2 as intprim22
return intprim22.sctid,intprim22.FSN
```

Comment: Hi Scott, a few things: can you share your database? Can you try to name your variables better? why don't you filter earlier for `definitionStatusId` ? MATCH (x1) is not needed. Otherwise what Martin said :)

Answer (score 1):

Your query looks very complicated. If I understand correctly, you want to find all `ObjectConcept` nodes that are "primitive" and have a parent and child that are "fully defined":

```
(ObjectConcept "fully defined")
   |
[:ISA]
   |
(ObjectConcept "primitive")  <-- find this?
   |
[:ISA]
   |
(ObjectConcept "fully defined")
```

I think you can simply match:

```
MATCH (oc_parent:ObjectConcept {definitionStatusId: 'fully'})-[:ISA]->
      (oc:ObjectConcept {definitionStatusId: 'primitive'})-[:ISA]->
      (oc_child:ObjectConcept {definitionStatusId: 'fully'})
RETURN oc_parent, oc, oc_child
```

All the `DISTINCT`, `collect()` and `UNWIND` do not necessarily make your query faster.

You should have an index on `definitionStatusId`:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :ObjectConcept(definitionStatusId)
```

### Update

You can query for the `ObjectConcepts` in a sub hierarchy first but the `[:ISA*]` query might look for very long paths and could be very expensive. 300.000 nodes is not that much, so the first solution might actually be faster. I would only do that if you really have to filter for a subset of the nodes.

```
// get the sub-hierarchy first
MATCH (:ObjectConcept {sctid:404684003})<-[:ISA*]-(oc:ObjectConcept {definitionStatusId: 'primitive'})
WITH oc
MATCH (oc_parent:ObjectConcept {definitionStatusId: 'fully'})-[:ISA]->
      (oc)-[:ISA]->
      (oc_child:ObjectConcept {definitionStatusId: 'fully'})
RETURN oc_parent, oc, oc_child
```

Comment: Thanks, Martin.  
I do have an index on :ObjectConcept(definitionStatusId)

You do understand my query with one exception.  The total "pool" of ObjectConcepts is 300,000 nodes.   So, I first need to get the concepts in the sub-hierarchy of interest.  This is the first MATCH on (a)<-[:ISA*]<-(b).

This first query takes approximately 20 minutes.

Comment: Hm ok. I also work with ontologies with similar numbers of nodes. Resolving the hierarchy from a given starting point shouldn't take 20 minutes. How long are the paths?

Comment: The longest path in this subhierarchy is at least 14 nodes.

The hierarchy can be traversed faster using groovy code, but I would prefer to use cypher.  Groovy can perform these traversals in sub 1 min.

Comment: I am running this query now:

MATCH (a:ObjectConcept{sctid:404684003})<-[:ISA*]-(b:ObjectConcept{definitionStatusId:900000000000073002})<-[:ISA*]-(c:ObjectConcept{definitionStatusId:900000000000074008})<-[:ISA*]-(d:ObjectConcept{definitionStatusID:900000000000073002})
with collect (DISTINCT c) as set1
UNWIND set1 as x1
return x1.sctid,x1.FSN

Comment: OK, you don't need the collect/UNWIND though. Just `RETURN DISTINCT c.sctid, c.FSN`

Answer (score 0):

The follow query produced a valid answer without crashing the web browser.  However, it still took an extended period of time to complete.  So, additional optimization is necessary.

```
//Find all subtypes of ObjectConcept
MATCH (a:ObjectConcept{sctid:404684003})<-[:ISA*]-(b:ObjectConcept{definitionStatusId:900000000000074008})
//Remove duplicate nodes
with distinct(b) as prim
//Remove leaf nodes
MATCH (prim)<-[:ISA*1..1]-()
with distinct(prim) as prim1
//Find all intermediate primitive nodes satisfying the requirements
MATCH (c:ObjectConcept{definitionStatusId:900000000000073002})<-[:ISA*]-(prim1)<-[:ISA*]-(d:ObjectConcept{definitionStatusId:900000000000073002})
return DISTINCT prim1.sctid,prim1.FSN
```